# AWSCli dynamodb update-item command syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

am using AmazonAwsCli to write a shell script to update an attribute in an item in a dynamodb table. I want to update an attribute in a table for multiple items. I am reading the attribute value from a file and am trying to update the table by injecting the value of the shell script variable in the command. The documentation available at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/update-item.html suggests using separate json files for expression-attribute-names and expression-attribute-values. However, I do not want to create separate json files. Rather, I want to write one command to update an item for a given attribute value.

```
My table name = MY_TABLE_NAME

hashkey = AccountId

shell script variable holding the value of AccountId = accountId

attribute name that needs to be updated = Version

shell script variable holding the value of Version = ver
```

I have got something like :

> aws dynamodb update-item --table-name MY_TABLE_NAME --key '{"AccountId": {"S": '$accountId'}}' --update-expression "SET Version = '{"Version": {"S": '$ver'}}'" --condition-expression "attribute_exists(Version)" --return-values UPDATED_NEW

But, the above command does not work. Can someone point me to the correct syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My AwsCli version did not support --update-expression option. I used the attribute-updates option instead.

Here is my command :

updatedVersion=`aws dynamodb update-item --table-name MY_TABLE_NAME --key '{"AccountId": {"S": '$accountId'}}' --attribute-updates '{"Version": {"Value": {"S": '$desiredVersion'},"Action": "PUT"}}' --return-values UPDATED_NEW | jq '.Attributes.RuleSetVersion.S'`

Answer (score 7):

Below is the update command with  `--update-expression`

```
 aws --region "us-east-1" dynamodb update-item \
 --table-name "MY_TABLE_NAME" --key \
 '{"Primary_Column_name":{"S":"Primary_Column_value"}}' \
 --update-expression 'SET #H = :h' \
 --expression-attribute-names '{"#H":"Column_name_to_change"}' \
 --expression-attribute-values '{":h":{"S":"Changed_Column_value"}}'
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers will work very good on MAC and Linux. 
If you want to run it on Windows, you need to use `"` quotes instead of `'` and double quotes `""` instead of a single quote "`"

Example:

```
aws dynamodb update-item --table-name MY_TABLE_NAME --key "{""PRIMARY_KEY_NAME"":{""S"":""PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE""}}" --update-expression "SET #G = :g"  --expression-attribute-names "{""#G"":""COLUMN_NAME_TO_UPDATE_VALUE""}" --expression-attribute-values "{"":g"":{""N"":""DESIRED_VALUE""}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with

1. pk and sk
2. array index accessing
3. reserved words in attribute-name and values

---

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name rulesets \
    --key '{"id":{"S":"cljr7n7tb0001pn6x30k869vf"}, "program":{"S":"cljr7n7tb0001pn6x30k869vf"}}' \
    --update-expression "SET steps[0].conditions.#a[1].#p = :ad" \
    --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 \
    --expression-attribute-values file://values.json \
    --expression-attribute-names file://attrs.json \
    --return-values ALL_NEW

Here
id => partition_key_col_name
program => sort_key_col_name


values.json
{
   ":ad" : {"S": "$.patient.dateOfBirth"}
}

attrs.json
{
    "#a" : "all",
    "#p" : "path"
}
```

We could also update json collections
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html